# How can I make a bottom border appear when I hover over a div?

Tags: html, css

I have some ***divs*** that I'm using as *navigation* buttons. I want a *thin black line* to appear on the *bottom* when I hover over them. I tried using `border-bottom` and it didn't work, but strangely `bottom-top` and `border-right` did work. Why?

```css
#box-a {
background: red;
grid-area: a;
}

#box-b {
background: blue;
grid-area: b;
}

#box-c {
background: green;
grid-area: c;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a a"
                       "b c";
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  }
  
.header-button {
            background: red;
            height: 50px;
            width: 80px;
            color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            }
            
.header-button:hover {
                  color: yellow;
                  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
                 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id=box-a>
      <div class=header-button>About</div>
      <div class=header-button>How to</div>
      <div class=header-button>Info</div>
      <div class=header-button>More</div>
    </div>
    <div id=box-b>
      <p>
      This is the content of box B.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id=box-c>
      <p>
      This is the content of box C.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your border-bottom is working as intended, not sure what you are looking for. Do you want a line directly below the textContent instead of below the divs bottom border? Also I placed your two snippits together into a working snippit.

Comment: It isn't working for me. When I hover over a button, the text changes from white to yellow but nothing else happens.

Comment: I've just noticed the 'run code' button. I didn't know I could do that. The code in the snippet does give a bottom border but it's only an extract of the entire code, so something must be going wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I have added more of the code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you have two issues:

1. Your height is specified in the child of your row and its children  are showing up underneath the next sibling element. If you inspect the elements and highlight them in code inspector it will show you the overflow going on there. So we remove the height on header button and let the 40px you have handle height in the `grid-template-rows` property of your grid parent.
2. Your bottom-border is showing up underneath the `box-b` and `box-c` elements, set there `z-index: -1` and the nav buttons will show up on top.

```css
#box-a {
  background: red;
  grid-area: a;
}

#box-b {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: b;
  z-index: -1;
}

#box-c {
  background: green;
  grid-area: c;
  z-index: -1;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a a" "b c";
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
}

.header-button {
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header-button:hover {
  color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id=box-a>
      <div class=header-button>About</div>
      <div class=header-button>How to</div>
      <div class=header-button>Info</div>
      <div class=header-button>More</div>
    </div>
    <div id=box-b>
      <p>
        This is the content of box B.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id=box-c>
      <p>
        This is the content of box C.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```